# Java создать файл в папке

Tags: java

Мне понадобилось создать файл в папке, но какие бы методы не пробовал — пишут ошибку. Звучат они все примерно так:

> (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)

так вот, у меня в проекте есть папка "Save" в ней нужно создать файл

я пробовал вот такой вариант:

```
String filePath = new File("Save").getAbsolutePath();
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(filePath + "\\test.txt");
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
```

и вот такой:

```
String filePath = new File("Save").getAbsolutePath();
File file = new File(filePath + "\\test.txt");
file.createNewFile();
```

всё бестолку.

В интернете нечего толкового не нашёл. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы проверяли `filePath`? Он указывает на правильную папку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, папку "Save" нужно было инициализировать как объект класса File, объявить директорией и потом уже создавать в ней файл.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File filePath = new File("Save");
    filePath.mkdir();
    File file = new File(filePath + "\\test.txt");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо всё заработало

Answer (score 2):

```
// создать все директории если их вдруг ещё нет path/to/files
Path dir = Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("path", "to", "files"));
// или так Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("path/to/files")); 
// создать собственно файл path/to/files/filename.ext
OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(dir.resolve("filename.ext"));
```